# How to change a game's resolution in windowed mode?

Tags: windows-7, resolution, gaming

Some games have option to run in windowed mode but how can I change the resolution of window mode itself? For example, Diablo 2 has a resolution 800x600 in window mode but I want to change it to 1280x720.

How can I do this and is it possible?

Comment: I'd be surprised if there's wasn't an option in the game itself to set the resolution, particularly in a big-budget game like Diablo.

Comment: @MichaelDunfield considering Diablo 2 came 13 years ago...

Answer (score 6):

Most games should have a resolution option built into them. Some games have the ability to do custom resolution from their settings files.

If there is not one, you can use external programs, such as [ShiftWindow](http://grismar.net/shiftwindow/) to try to force another custom resolution. (See width and height in the screenshot below)

Unfortunately, some games get visual artifacts or refuse to work completely when their resolution is forced by a 3rd party program. You will have to test this for your game(s).

[image: Shiftwindow UI]

Comment: I tried ShiftWindow and i was able to change the resolution to 1280x720 of Diablo 2 but it doesn't keep the aspect ratio and stretches the game graphic. I don't know if something can be done about this. May be the game doesn't support custom resolution.

Comment: @peter7558 I don't think there's much you can do about it, unless there's a setting or a mod for the game. [This question over on Arqade might help you a bit with Diablo 2](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1193/is-there-a-way-to-increase-the-resolution-for-diablo-ii-past-what-the-game-allow/1195#1195)

Answer (score 2):

Autohotkey has a `WinMove` function that can accomplish this in a keyed script.  It would look something like:

```
^!g::
WinGetTitle, currentWindow, A
IfWinExist %currentWindow%
{
   WinMove, , , 0, 0, 1280, 720
}   
return
```

That creates a hotkey <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> to resize your current window.

More details are on the [Gaming Stack Exchange](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/17307/7413).

Answer (score 0):

If the other options work but the mouse or other input gets messed up check out [IntegerScaler][1]. It scales up any window to match the screen's size and it was the only program that worked for me without the mouse messing up in my game.